# Should we choose Java over C# for new project?

Tags: c#, java, linux

We have a team of .net developers (C#) with a range of experience from 2 to 6 yrs. Over the last few years we have been developing Silverlight/Aps.net MVC/WPF applications, however there is a new two year project which means we will develop a html5 application on linux.

The company I work for would like all developers across their offices to use the same programming language which is Java. Although there is talk of using mono but using the same language and sharing modules/services/etc already created in Java are the main reason for moving to Java.

Some of the developers here are upset and I would like to find positive in moving over that will convince the other developers?

Any ideas?

JD

Comment: this question should be asked in programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I know that if I was in the position of being asked to go from C# to Java id sooner find another job. I find Java horrible to work with and every large Java project I've been involved with ends up being riddled with legacy bugs and almost completely unmanageable. That was most likley because of what we were working on and the Java libs we had to rely on but over all I find Java programming is not an enjoyable process.

Comment: @Henry: How much experience (months/yrs) do you have in Java/C#? Legacy bugs, can you tell me more?

Comment: Java I had around 2 years on and off as for C# about 3 years now. The problems we had with Java largely arose when trying to create a front end and certain issues with RMI. Quite regularly we would find a bug that caused it to eat 100% of CPU and gobble up the ram and when we found the bug entry it had been posted in some occasions up to 3 or even 4 years ago and had been left completely unattended. I know you were looking for positives, apologies for not being much help!

Comment: @Henry: Thanks, I'd rather know in advance of issues. I personally don't mind the learning side as long as there is a planned route (training and expectations of deadlines) thought through. What I wont be happy with are "legacy" issues that the developers never experienced with .net.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is no for your situation. If your team if developers are experienced in .NET, then picking up Java may pose some learning curves to your team.

I have seen "enterprise" applications built with Java, without the correct people and skill sets, they are no where near anything.

Given the advancement of .NET, sharepoint, and C#, there should be no reason for stepping in Java for the reasons you listed. 2Cents.

Comment: He said the company wants to move to Java, not asked if it was a good idea. So since they are doing it anyway, he wants reasons to convince his colleagues.

Comment: @Chin: There will be a training budget but not sure if that will be enough. Would that help?

Comment: @kheldar Yes, i gone past his question, i am getting into the root of the situation. To convince him out.

Answer (score 2):

Using Mono would probably not work out anyway, we tried this and found too many incompatibilities yet for our purposes. IMHO, Mono is great to start a multi platform .Net project, not to convert an ecosystem to Linux.

On a programmer's perspective, it's always a good thing to switch technologies once in a while, it avoids intellectual rot :p

Silverlight, as far as I'm concerned, is a dying technology that never really competed with Flash and is being replaced by HTML5 at a very fast pace due to iPhones, iPads, Androids and the amazing growth of Macs. Its only real strength lies in the Microsoft ecosystem. Since your problem is precisely to switch to HTML 5, it makes sense to use a technology that is agnostic to the presentation layer, such as Java. Since only Java and .Net yield strong enough an ecosystem, it only leaves moving your developers to Java as a solution. Good programmers in .Net should not have that much pain transferring to the Java world anyway, it's still managed, OO, and basically verbose :P

Comment: Thanks. Mono has been talked about and atleast the team will be happy for a while but what sort of incompatibilities did you find? This is a new HTML5 app with the back end as an Asp.net MVC type web app.

Comment: @JD I believe windows exclusive libraries are left out, which you probably don't use anyway and bleeding edge technologies; although in a few cases mono has releaseda new .net feature before Microsoft. Asp.net mono is picking up speed and desktop mono has been used in some programs just for Linux

Comment: Yes, some Microsoft libraries are out, but of course, some coders who left the company used them. Since we're not going to rewrite all that code ... :D It's called "legacy" ;)

Answer (score 0):

For your project, you need to use the skills set your developer currently have.

However, if the business really wants you to change you should talk to them about how they can invest in their staff to make this happen. e.g. training and accepting longer development times for the project.  If they are not willing to do this they can't seriously expect you to deliver a Java project in the same time to the same standard as a .NET one as you don't have the right skills to do that.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Unless they are personally driven to work in java and he secided platform not much you can really do motivate/convert them. It is like asking them to move away from their specialization. Going mono may be a good compromise but may not align with  enterprise plan of one language strategy.If not carefully manage I think you will run a big risk of losing them overtime but a new team may also align better with the direction